# How to draw 'arc' the angle sign in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wondering how to draw this kind of arc in the angle with Matplotlib. I tried `matplotlib.patches.Arc`, but it has quite many parameters to adjust, for instance it must be provided with centres of the ellipsis.

[image]

So is there any faster or intuitive way of drawing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is an open issue on github. A working example should be provided soon. You can follow the process [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12518) and the example is hosted [here](https://25160-1385122-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/angle_marker.html). I just posted the link, because the code is rather long.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example under the Matplotlib  Gallery, **[scale invariant angle label](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/angle_annotation.html)**.